# vba parenthesis

Tags: excel, vba, formula, parentheses

struggling to get the parenthesis in the right spot. this is formula in a specified range in vba macro

```
Range("C" & i).Formula = "=INDEX($C$1:$C$2,MATCH(" * "&TRIM(RIGHT(A" & i & ",LEN(A" & i & ")-FIND(" - ",A" & i & ")))&" * ",$A$1:$A$2,0),0)"
```

Comment: Looks correct to me, how are you using it in vba, please show your actual code.

Comment: it is the ampersand and wildcards throwing me off.

Comment: All `"` inside the formula need to be doubled `""` Except where it is around vba `" & i & "` and remove the spaces around the `*`

Comment: Also you do not need to loop to put in a formula  Excel will make the changes to the formula relatively when entered in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should be..

```
.Formula = "=INDEX($C$1:$C$2,MATCH(""*"" & TRIM(RIGHT(A8,LEN(A8)-FIND(""-"",A8)))& ""*"",$A$1:$A$2,0),0)"
```